# Dynamic HTML depending on GET request parameters?

Tags: angularjs, scala

Suppose I have a RESTful web server. I would like to load dynamic HTML based on the request.

If the browser sends an HTTP GET request for `/user/123`, I would like to load an HTML page that is customized for User #123, which I have data on back in my database.

So for example, if User #123 had the name "Foo" in my DB, I would like to render an HTML page saying "Hello, Foo!".

How would I do this? The front-end is AngularJS, and back-end is Scala.

The Scala back-end can retrieve the Name of User #123 front the DB. But I don't know how to send this information back to the browser, since I don't know of a way to embed code in the HTML like you could in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty fundamental use case scenario for AngularJS.  You load the variable from the Scala server, formatted as JSON, as the response to an AngularJS GET request.  Then you take the response to that (see docs for Angular $http.get), map it to something in the applicable AngularJS controller's scope, and then interpolate it:

```
<div ng-controller="whateverController">
  {{ user.name }}
</div>
```

As for how you generally run a web server in Scala...that's even more vague than the rest of your question.

Comment: Ah, ok I think the key point I am missing here is that there is only a *single* page in the application.

Instead of serving multiple separate pages from the server, we just dynamically load DOM elements using Angular. Is this correct?

Comment: That really depends on your application.  Technically, you can model your entire application as pre-loaded partials, but it may suit your needs better to load them dynamically from the server, as templates.  The meaning of "Single-Page Application" can be communicated somewhat accurately by saying that your browser, after loading the application, will only manipulate the DOM,, instead of reloading it all from scratch.